# NoMethodError O'Reilley example

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

Working through the classes section in the O'reilley book and they seem to be indicating the below should work:

```
class Point
  def initialize(x,y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end

  def x
    @x
  end

  def y
    @y
  end

  def to_s
    "(#@x,#@y)"
  end
end

p = Point.new(5,0)
q = Point.new(p.x*2, p.y*2)
q.x = 0
puts q.x
```

In theory, I'm expecting it to print 0, instead my compiler is returning a `NoMethodError` upon trying to perform `q.x = 0`. Anything jumping out at you guys?

Comment: `"(#@x,#@y)"` should be `"(#{@x},#{@y})"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should not work, as there is no method `x=` defined (as per the error message). There might be an errata online?

Comment: Not sure it's necessarily errata, but certainly not clearly defined in the text, thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, an assignment operation for classes is yet another method, so that you should add following to your code:

```
class Point
  def x=(value)
    @x = value
  end

  def y=(value)
    @y = value
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

q.x = 0 can work only when you have a setter for x in Point class

```
def x=(x)
  @x=x
end
```